# mention a member with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

Hello I wanna mention a specific member in my guild I know my code is a mess can you show me my mistakes please?

```
async def ping(ctx):
    guild=ctx.guild(889583100286369832)
    sido=guild.get_member('439800066312503297')
    await ctx.send(sido.mention)
```

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: I am getting an error

Comment: Post the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

```
sido = await bot.fetch_user(439800066312503297)
await ctx.send(sido.mention)
```

You need intents for this:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the error message yet. but discord requires a special intent to get guild data about users.

[image]

You don't need the guild data on a user to @ them however, so you shouldn't need to enable that. you can do this:

```py
myid = '<@[ID GOES HERE]>'
await client.send_message(message.channel, ' : %s is the best ' % myid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the error, I'm unsure if this is the problem but `guild` likely doesn't have a `get_member()` method and you should instead use `bot.get_member()`

In the event that this *isn't* the cause of your problem, the best way to workaround this issue for your specific use case would be to mention the user with `<@ID>`

```
await ctx.send("<@{}>".format("439800066312503297"))
# Or
await ctx.send("<@439800066312503297>")
```

Formatting here is unnecessary if you want to hard-code the ID, but I recommend using it if you want to dynamically change the ID in the future.